# Code is not working: unhandled OleDbException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

Below not working code using ms access database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\IT1\My Documents\Downloads\examples\demo1\kk.accdb";
    conn.Open();
   string sql = "Select * from Category Where CategoryID IN (Select CategoryID from Product3)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds, "Category3");
    ad.Dispose();

    sql = "Select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.CategoryID from Product p";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(ds, "Product");
    ad.Dispose();

    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("CategoriesRelation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["CategoryID"],
    ds.Tables[1].Columns["CategoryID"]));
    outerRep.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    outerRep.DataBind();
 }


protected void outerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        Repeater innerRep = e.Item.FindControl("innerRep") as Repeater;
        innerRep.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("CategoriesRelation");
        innerRep.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I am using a nested repeater to display product according to category. Its giving error on dataset filling time. Below is a link of my error:

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: instead of posting a link to an error that some users (i.e me) aren't willing to click on... post the actual error

Comment: This is my error: http://postimg.org/image/sp9ajzfxh/

Comment: I think my first comment was pretty clear.

Comment: My code error: "Syntax error in query expression 'CategoryID IN (Select CategoryID from Product3) Select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.ImageUrl,p.VideoName,p.VideoSize,p.CategoryID from Product3 p'."

Comment: Did you try the SQL? Seems you have 2 SQL statement, but wanna put into 1 data table...

Comment: I had implemented my code according to this example. @Alex http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/showing-category-and-subcategory-using-nested-repeater-in-as/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should fill `DataTable` one by one

```
private void BindData()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\IT1\My Documents\Downloads\examples\demo1\kk.accdb";
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "Select * from Category3 Where CategoryID IN (Select CategoryID from Product3)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter ad=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds, "Category3");
    ad.Dispose();

    sql = "Select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.ImgUrl,p.VideoName,p.VideoSize,p.CategoryID from Product3 p";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    ad=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(ds, "Product3");
    ad.Dispose();

    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("CategoriesRelation",ds.Tables[0].Columns["CategoryID"],
    ds.Tables[1].Columns["CategoryID"]));
    outerRep.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
    outerRep.DataBind();
 }
```

**Edit**

Update with table schema

Comment: Getting error: CS0128: A local variable named 'sql' is already defined in this scope

Comment: @user3793996 I'm sorry, I have remove the `string sql` in code

Comment: @user3793996 Sorry, I cannot access image host in my network, would you post the exception here?

Comment: @user3793996, i assume that CategoryID form Category3 table and CategoryID from Product3 table aren't of the same datatype. They should be each of type `Int`

Comment: In this line getting error: ad.Fill(ds, "Category3");. Type mismatch in expression. @Alex

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  But again getting an error. ad.Fill(ds, "Product3"); No value given for one or more required parameters. @ Heslacher

Comment: @user3793996 Please update you question with the current code

Comment: I had updated above question. And now getting error in this line:  ad.Fill(ds, "Product3"); No value given for one or more required parameters. @Heslacher

Comment: @user3793996 may you post your table schema in your question?

Comment: Try changing `sql = "Select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.ImageUrl,p.VideoName,p.VideoSize,p.CategoryID from Product3 p";` to `sql = "Select PID,ImageName,ImageUrl,VideoName,VideoSize,CategoryID from Product3";`

Comment: Again error on same line: No value given for one or more required parameters. And see my database design tables: http://postimg.org/image/anzcdo0o5/ . @Heslacher

Comment: See my database design tables: postimg.org/image/anzcdo0o5 . @Alex

Comment: @user3793996 ... you changed the column name `ImageUrl` to `ImgUrl`... and again, please post text instead of image, your image host is act strange in my mobile...

Comment: I got the result. Thanks @ Alex

Comment: I got the result. Thanks @ Heslacher

Answer (score 1):

This select statement won't work:

```
string sql = "Select * from Category3 
    Where CategoryID IN (Select CategoryID from Product3) 
    Select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.ImageUrl,p.VideoName,p.VideoSize,p.CategoryID 
    from Product3 p ";
```

change it to:

```
string sql = "Select * from Category3 
    Where CategoryID IN (Select CategoryID from Product3)";
```

Also check out: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I had implemented my code according to this example. @Heslacher  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/showing-category-and-subcategory-using-nested-repeater-in-as/

Comment: The sample shown on your link is a stored procedure

Comment: If you need both select statements, you need to go with @Alex answer

Comment: @user3793996 interesting, but the example use stored procedure, which it will return 2 result set, however, you cannot just copy SQL statement in SP to `CommandText`